# How to search product based on title and content in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, title

I want to apply a product search on title and content in wordpress using AJAX.

I have to used wp_query for search purpose but don't know how to bind based on search done by title and content.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass an "s" parameter. That "s" parameter search into the title and the content.

Comment: when i will pass parameter in "s" parameter it will automatically search for both title and content.
have you any post related that ?